# Does hasAttribute() under IE8+ is supported?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, mozilla

I've checked the MDN and Microsoft Websites and they both say Element.hasAttribute() is supported in Internet Explorer from Version 8. I am using hasAttribute in my app and I have created a jsFiddle to test in IE9 just to make sure. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/vbwfzudv/) is the fiddle I am using in IE8 and 9 and I am not getting the 2nd alert. Is hasAttribute truly supported or am I missing something? Also this is my first question on here and I've searched to make sure there are no duplicates but if there are I apologize, thank you for any assistance!

EDIT: It would seem that the fiddle only doesn't show the hasAttribute alert in IE9. IE8 yields correct results

```
<div id="bob">hi</div>

var test = document.getElementById( 'bob' );
alert( test.innerHTML );
alert( test.hasAttribute( 'id' ) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make the test in  windows 7 with IE 8 and IE9 and works, here are the screenshots.

[image: IE8]

[image: IE9]

Comment: Hmm ok maybe it has to do something with the VM's we are using for IE8 and 9 we all have Macs here so test IE in VMs which are pretty finicky, thanks for the screen shots

Comment: you're welcome, I recommend this [link](https://www.browserstack.com), is very useful and please don't forget mark my answer as Correct.

Comment: hehe I'm not begging I just remember to people to mark the answer as correct if they think that, don't be envious your answer is really good too ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks perfect ...

If you really want to check whether a particular attr exist or not....
then try like this

```
if ((element.getAttribute('id') === null) || (element.getAttribute('id') === ''))
```

Comment: Thanks I was thinking about doing this before posting my question thinking I was missing something, seems I still am but to make sure I don't run into any pitfalls I'll use this